# IF inside try block

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

I want to execute my method **callmethod** if the condition inside the IF statement is met. Else it should execute the catch block. But during implementation, if the condition is not met, it does not go to the catch block.

```
try{
if(count==0)
callmethod();
}
catch (Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: A catch block is entered if an exception is thrown, that is - given your description - not the case. If you want an alternative handling, you need to use `else`

Comment: in your else statement (which you don't have) thrown an exception and it will get caught in the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to hit the catch block, you need to throw an exception if your parameter is not met (i.e. count != 0).

Example:

```
try {
    if(count==0){
        callmethod();
    } else {
        throw new SomeException("some message");
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Just with the IF statement, can I catch the exception

Comment: So you want an exception to be thrown if count != 0, but not thrown if an exception occurs during callMethod()?

Comment: The problem is any code that you call inside try { } will be caught by the catch block when an exception is thrown. You should re-think why you need to use try/catch at all. You are better off just calling if (count !=0) callMethod() if that's the case

Comment: What if I put the try catch inside the IF statement

Comment: But why are you throwing an exception if you will catch it 100% of the time? You can always just error log for example: Log.e(TAG, "log your error message here") and achieve the same functionality as you posted

Comment: For my log, it need a throwable error as its parameter

Answer (score 3):

This is a good application for methods:

```
try {
  if (count == 0) {
    callOneMethod();
  }
  else {
    callOtherMethod();
  }
catch (Exception e) {
  callOtherMethod();
}
```

That way you don't have any duplicated code and you're not doing weird things with exceptions in non-exceptional cases.